# Generic way of referencing parent class in Java

Tags: java

I have some code that I need to reuse in several Java apps. That code implements a GUI which in turn needs to access some static variables and methods from the calling class. Those variables and methods are always called the same in all of the apps. Is there a generic way to obtain a handle to the calling class in Java so the code for "someGUI" class can remain untouched and in fact come from the same source file for all the different apps?

Minimal working example:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class test {
  static int variable = 123;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    someGUI sg = new someGUI();
    sg.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class someGUI extends JFrame {
  public someGUI() {
    System.out.println(String.format("test.variable = %d", test.variable));
  }
}
```

How can I "generify" the reference to "test" in test.variable to always just refer to the calling class? It's not the "super" class, at least using super.variable doesn't work.

Comment: You can pass `test.variable` in the constructor of someGUI, instead of refering it in someGUI constructor, it will make loose coupling.

Comment: that would make for difficult maintenance later on.. keep it decoupled and passed those as params to someGUI contstructor or to some init function of some sort as Naman mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would advise against this approach since there are only brittle ways to implement it. You should parameterize `SomeGUI` with a parameter containing the values you need instead.

However, it is possible to do what you ask by examining the thread's stack trace and using reflection to access the static fields by name. For example like this:

```
class Test {
    static int variable = 123;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeGUI sg = new SomeGUI();
    }

    static class SomeGUI extends JFrame {

        public SomeGUI() throws Exception {
            StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            // stackTrace[0] is getStackTrace(), stackTrace[1] is SomeGUI(),
            // stackTrace[2] is the point where our object is constructed.
            StackTraceElement callingStackTraceElement = stackTrace[2];
            String className = callingStackTraceElement.getClassName();
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(className);
            Field declaredField = c.getDeclaredField("variable");
            Object value = declaredField.get(null);
            System.out.println(String.format("test.variable = %d", value));
        }
    }
}
```

This will print `test.variable = 123`.

Obviously this is sensitive to renaming of the variables. It is also sensitive to dynamic proxies.

Also, it should be noted that you need to do this in the constructor. If you try to do this kind of lookup in other methods you can not find out how the instance was created.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no inheritance between somGUI and test, 
   Actual inheritance is there between someGUI and JFrame.
   If you use super(), JVM tries to find 'variable' in JFrame, that is not what you wanted.
2. Use static methods setters & getters to access the 'variable' instead of direct accessing them.

Comment: Well there's a fair bit of nitpicking and OO riding going on above... none are actually answering my question. You are closest thus far, and the first one to realise that indeed this is not an inheritance issue! It seems odd though, I cannot imagine that there is no way for someGUI to figure out what class it was instantiated in? There must be some kind of function that allows a class to explore who instantiated a copy of itself?